# How to use eclipse to export jar with ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I try to export ant buildfile , then i run the build.xml. Then what next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A i recall you can right-click on the build.xml and select Run>Ant Build, it will automaticly create the jar, from your configuration!! Here is an quick example:

[image]

Comment: can i know where is the jar file?

Comment: The jar file target location is specified inside the ant build script (`build.xml`)

Comment: Look in the build.xml file.  All the information, such as where WAR and JAR files are copied to, are set inside of the build.xml.  You also need to make sure your build.xml is configured to build JAR files.  Google is your friend.  Do a search on building JAR from build.xml and some examples are bound to come up :)

Comment: As far as I can see the automatically generated `build.xml` prepares the `bin` tree. In other words it does compiling which is the creation of `.class` files and the copying of resources. I don't see any `jar` target in the automatically generated `build.xml`.